# How to uninstall Apache libcloud?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, libcloud

I want to completely uninstall Apache libcloud.
Location of libcloud

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libcloud
```

I have used this command to uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove python-libcloud
```

Error while trying to install again

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): backports.ssl-match-hostname in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from apache-libcloud==0.18.0)
```

Also, libcloud folder is not removed after uninstalling
Please suggest a right way to uninstall.

Comment: That depends a lot on how you installed it in the first place. You may want to add some information to your question.

Comment: First time installation:
    apt-get install python-libcloud

,Second time upgrade:
pip install --upgrade apache-libcloud==0.18.0

Answer (score 2):

`pip uninstall <package-name>`

From the [pip reference page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/). First Google search result.

and

`sudo apt-get uninstall --purge <package-name>`

From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application) or [the official apt-get documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/apt-get.html)

Regards,
Lisenby